# CiviCRM will not recognize valid email address

Tags: contacts, validation

I am trying to add a new email address for an existing contact. The address is valid. However, the new address will not save and I received this message:
**Please enter a valid email address**

The address is: valerie.king@lottery.nh.gov

How can I get the change accepted and saved?

Comment: How did you try adding email address? Through contact form or profile? Since I couldn't replicate the error on http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

Comment: I hit this all the time - but in my case it's because somehow I add a leading or trailing space when I copy & paste - could it be that?

Comment: I tried typing it in the profile.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I just retried and it saved. Oh happy day!!

Comment: I bet you were correct re. spacing issues in the copy and paste.

Answer (score 3):

The client-side validation in CiviCRM will flag any invisible or space characters which get pasted in along with an email address or URL. The non-printing characters are the trickiest to find, including things like carriage returns and line feeds that seem to get swept up in some copy-paste operations. I encounter this problem relatively frequently, but it is hard to pinpoint the exact combination of platform, browser, and source.

Therefore, if I have an e-mail address or URL which doesn't seem to take even though it appears to be well-formed, I "clear" the characters by pasting someplace else first, like the `To:` field in an e-mail or the URL bar in the browser. This strips out the non-ASCII characters, and I can then re-select the desired text and paste it into CiviCRM as usual.